# Design an algorithm to find the average distance between two path

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a database of time-stamped points which represent a path being drawn by a user in a 2-D plane. I also have a list of points which represent the goal path. These are not timestamped. I want to find how accurate the users' drawn paths are as compared to the goal path. The parameter to define accuracy is not clear and something I'm trying to decide. I don't really care about the temporal aspect of the user drawn path. I only want to compare the two paths.

I'm doing this to do the analysis for an experiment done by a behavioral lab. This is my current algorithm.

1. Find the total distance of the user drawn path by adding the straight line difference between all points.
2. At every 1% of the total distance of both the user path and the goal path find the straight line distance between the two paths.
3. Average the 100 points together to get the total average distance between the two paths.
4. Increase the sampling frequency if I want to have a more accurate number

I'm only looking for algorithmic help since implementing this would be quite trivial. My issue is that I'm not sure whether I'm missing something here, and nor sure of the correctness of this algorithm and wanted to run it by some experienced programmers.

I'm not a programmer by trade but this data analysis is essential for the paper the lab is working on. I'm not sure if I need to be familiar with some higher level Math which makes this trivial.

I'm completely language agnostics and would appreciate any pointers to any existing algorithms or novel solutions which solve this problem.

Comment: I think the distance function you define is a good start. To define a better function it would be necessary to know your exact requirements to the distance function: do you want it to be translation and/or rotation invariant? Do you want to allow shifts like [dynamic time wraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) for time series? There are many ideas that you could draw from time series, trajectory and polyline similarity epending on what your needs are.

Comment: Why are you re-sampling the user path instead of just using the points you have?  That seems to introduce more error. You assume that a straight line fit is reasonable, instead of fitting some curve if you really need to resample.

Comment: Is average distance a good metric, or are you supposed to measure similarity? You can easily construct non-parallel paths with lower average distance than a more intuitively similar-looking one.

Comment: @Useless I don't think I was very clear there. By re-sampling I simply meant finding a point in the data which is the closest to the 1% of the total distance. The issue is that some users drew the first 75% of the path in less than a minute and then spent over 5 minutes drawing the alst 25%. But the location data was collected at a standard interval.  So I have a lot lower "resolution" of points for the first 75% as compared to the last 25%. In some cases it is so extreme that I'll have to extrapolate the coordinates to find the point closest to the 1% parameter I have described.

Comment: @Useless But you are completely correct that I should try to use the existing points as long as possible. Also to respond to your second comment, I was hoping to find a  better metric than average distance, but so far I have not been able to define a better parameter which represents similarity. I'm completely open to any suggestions you might have on that front. This is real issue because I have tried to "break" the algorithim by trying to draw paths which minimize average distance but intutively do not look look similiar at all. This is the main issue I'm trying to tackle.

Comment: @SaiBot I wasn't aware of the concept of time series and especially DTWs. On googling a little more, I found this very illuminating publication which might help me out. This is the publication [FastDTW - Toward Accurate Dynamic Time Warping in Linear Time and Space](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/05a2/0cde15e172fc82f32774dd0cf4fe5827cad2.pdf)  and also an existing python implementation based on it [fastdtw](https://github.com/slaypni/fastdtw). Thank you!

Comment: @SteepLearningCurve be aware that this is not directly applicable since time series are different from 2D polylines. However the concept has been carried over to trajectories. You might find [this Github repo](https://github.com/bguillouet/traj-dist) a good resource that includes implementations and literature. However, none of these are translation/rotation invariant (which sounds like you will need it in your use case), so if you want to include this, you could add some preprocessing

Comment: Instead of sampling along both paths each 1% of the total, you could sample each 1% along the user path and compute the distance of each point on the user path to the closest point *anywhere* on the goal path. This would ensure that a deviation at the start didn't effect the rest of the path (even where the lines align).

Comment: OK, so if you want to measure similarity, you could allow (bounded) scaling and translation (eg. measure the centroid and extent for each path, translate so the centroids coincide and scale so the extents match, and _then_ measure average distance). You could also filter out points with much higher than mean error, and/or fit curves to compare, and/or also compare derivatives to get some sense of the similarity of curve shape. And so on and so on. There's a lot of stuff you _could_ do, and a long way to go before you have a definite programming question, IMO.